# Cannot find module 'socket.io' windows 10

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have windows 10 machine and when I try to run my script it's throw error
Cannot find module 'socket.io'

```
server.listen(8089);
// use socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) (from your command prompt) to ensure the `socket.io` package is installed before use.

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

The `--save` flag will add the given dependency to your application's `package.json` for easier installation in the future